Help me identify this component: ST (e3) G ME GP647
Can anyone help me identify this component? PCB corroded, and it came off.


If you want to attract the attention of someone who might know then put the part name in the title and number of terminals.

That should be an ST SM6T18CA bidirectional transil diode, according to this datasheet. As indicated by marking "ME".

You forgot to include that the "ME" marking means it's a BIDIRECTIONAL diode. ;)

@EdinFifić SM6T18CA already states that it's bi-directional. The uni-directional counterpart is SM6T18A.

@Velvet "CA" is in the model number, but we are talking about the MARKING on the part itself. Do you see a CA in the photo of the part?

@Velvet We are talking about the MARKING on the body, and you are talking about the MODEL of the TVS. Speaking of which, I don't see anything in the datasheet indicating that this could be the right model as indicated in the posted picture.

@EdinFifić Not sure what you mean with ""CA" is in the model number, but we are talking about the MARKING". Marking = EE -> SM6T18A, Marking = ME -> SM6T18CA (https://i.sstatic.net/Ie6TfHWk.png)

@Velvet The question was asked about the MARKING on the part itself, and the answer says "as indicated by marking "ME". So, both the question and the answer are talking about the MARKING "ME", and the part number is mentioned as the guessed one. So I don't know what you don't understand in my comments.

@EdinFifić (Okay, one last effort). You told the OP to include that "ME" means that it's a bi-directional diode. I only stated that this information would be unnecessary, because the part number SM6T18CA already specifies ALL information, including that it's a bi-directional diode. ME => SM6T18CA is sufficient as an answer. Then, for whatever reason, you diverted the discussion to "CA" not being visible in the photo. I know "CA" is not marked on the part. I never said anything of that sort.

@Velvet It may be that you didn't see the related answer before my first comment, when the word "bidirectional" was not included at all, while the words "As indicated by the marking "ME"" were included, so that's why I pointed it out. Your comment stands that the "CA" part also indicates a bidirectional model. The author modified his answer after my first comment to include the word "bidirectional", and that's when you pitched in. That may be the point of our misunderstanding.
